# Single Crawl script to Crawl website (Nutch) and Index results (Solr)

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, web-crawler, nutch

I am new to Nutch and Solr. I have just taken over the activities and I have to crawl and index my website now.

These are the steps I have been asked to follow.

- Delete the crawl folders (apache-nutch-1.10\crawl)
- Remove the existing indexes:

> Solr-Admin-> Skyweb->Documents->Document Type (xml) and execute
>   *:*

- Go to Solr-Admin -> Core Admin -> Click on 'Reload' and then 'Optimize'
- And run the crawl job using the following command:

> bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://IP:8080/solr/website/ urls/
>   crawl/ 5

I did some research and felt that doing these tasks manually is overwork and the script should take care of all the above tasks.

So my queries\concerns are:

*Doesn't the above script take care of the entire process? Do I still need to delete the crawl folders and clear the existing indexes manually?*

*What is the relevance of the Admin tasks - 'Reload' and 'Optimize'?*

*Can I cron schedule the the crawl script to run weekly and will it take care of the entire process?*

*How else can I automate the crawling and indexing to run periodically?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible ways:

1. configure Nutch to re-fetch all previously crawled pages after one week, see the property `db.fetch.interval.default`. Keep the crawl/ folder and the Solr index as is. Nutch will automatically delete gone pages from Solr. Ev. you should delete old segments after each crawl (`rm -rf crawl/segments/*`) to avoid that the disk fills up over time.
2. launch each crawl from scratch (just remove the folder `crawl/` before calling `bin/crawl`. It's also possible to delete a Solr index from command-line, e.g. by firing:

   `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data '<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
   curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'`

It's not difficult to combine these commands and including the call of `bin/crawl` in a short shell script which can be called by cronjob. Of course, it's also easy to modify the script `bin/crawl` to your own needs.

Comment: Thanks. Couple of queries. I believe I will stick with the second way and wrtie a script for the same. But my queries are 1. if the interval.default is 30 days - running a crawl job  <30 days wouldn't update anything? That is the schedule of the crawl job should always be greater than the interval? 2. Also, is it required to do a Reload and Optimize everytime? Is it possible to add in the scripts?

Comment: > 1. if the interval.default is 30 days - running a crawl job <30 days wouldn't update anything?
Yes, correct.
> That is the schedule of the crawl job should always be greater than the interval?
It depends on the size of the crawl. For a larger crawl it may be enough to update a part of the content every time a crawl is scheduled.

See also the adaptive scoring FetchSchedule class.

> required to do a Reload and Optimize everytime?
Afaik, that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Chillax ! Just Relax !! Have you ever looked into Apache  ManifoldCF project ? It provides a clean interface to crawl web pages , better than Nutch , to lessen the hassle . It is open Source and within a matter of few minutes you can set up a Job with all your parameters and index your data in Server of your choice , be it Solr , Elastic Search , etc . And , once you set up a Job , you can save settings , so that you don't have to intermittently configure things . Also it supports a Rest API that surely allows you to automate your jobs on the fly . Google it . You won't regret . Hope that helps :) .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But nutch has been already installed and configured  - and I wouldn't want to change it for now. I need to stick on to nutch :-(